# Thread is created but not executed

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, atl

I have a DLL which is used by an ATL-COM component. Inside my DLL, a method StartMonitoring gets called from FinalConstruct. I want to create background thread inside StartMonitoring(), but the thread is created and a valid handle is returned yet the code inside the thread never gets executed. Does this have to do something with the way ATL components work? Please excuse me if its a dumb question but i do not have any ATL/COM understanding.

Here i believe it has something to with the way COM works. In my case i need StartMonitoring to start a background thread and when StopMonitoring is called from FinalRelease() will signal this background thread to quit and then Wait for it to quit. Now because the Thread is not started but have given a valid handle, StopMonitoring will signal and wait for ever. If i forcibly end StopMonitoring by bypassing Wait and return to FinalRelease(), MonitorThreadProc then starts execution.

```
unsigned int WINAPI CMonitor::MonitorThreadProc(LPVOID lpvParam)
{
    std::cout << "Enter MonitorThreadProc" << endl;   //Never hits this
    if (lpvParam == nullptr)
        return 1;

    CMonitor *pMonitor = static_cast<CMonitor*>(lpvParam);
    return (unsigned int)pMonitor->Run();
}

void CMonitor::StopMonitoring()
{

    if(m_EvtReg)
    {
        m_EvtStopMonitoring.Set();
        DWORD dwResult = ::WaitForSingleObject(m_hThread, INFINITE);
        if(dwResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            cout<<"Thread terminated"<<endl;
        }

    }
    m_EvtReg.Close();
    m_EvtStopMonitoring.Close();
    HANDLE h = m_hThread.Detach();
    CloseHandle(h);
}

bool CMonitor::StartMonitoring()
{

    int num = 0;
    unsigned int nThreadId = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, MonitorThreadProc, (LPVOID)this, 0, &nThreadId);
    if(hThread == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //I get a valid handle from _beginthreadex, but the thread never gets executed.
    m_hThread.Attach(hThread);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Any chance `StartMonitoring` is called from `DllMain`

Comment: @rustyx Problem is not with the _beginthreadex, i have used it in plenty of code and not a new thing. Here i believe it has something to with the way COM works. In my case i need StartMonitoring to start a background thread and when StopMonitoring is called it will signal this background thread to quit and then Wait for it to quit. Now because the Thread is not started but have given a valid handle, StopMonitoring will signal and wait for ever. If i forcibly end StopMonitoring by bypassing Wait, then the MonitorThreadProc executes, which is totally out of sink

Comment: When you are expecting that `MonitorThreadProc` starts and it does not, I think you could break in with debugger and check threads. Perhaps something there suggests what exactly is locked and prevents from new thread to start.

Comment: If the COM server calls it while itself being loaded (i.e. from its DllMain), thread creation will fail.

Comment: @RomanR.The thread just is created and thats it, the callstack shows just ntdll.dll!78d820c kind of frame. And it only starts working after FinalRelease is done which is pointless in my case

Comment: @rustyx StartMonitoring is called from FinalConstruct(). So its not DLLMain

Comment: The odds that you can see std::cout output from an ATL component are rather low.  It is not obvious why you use cout at all, you of course favor using a debugger breakpoint instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm able to see cout working on main thread. Anyways, have debugger connected and never seen the BG thread being executed until the Main thread is done with its work, Only after that BG starts execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odd behaviour was due to the loader lock held during the DLL load . Until the loader lock is held , thread is never scheduled and hence I was not seeing the code execution.